# Медленный запрос в MySQL с группировкой

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация

Есть такая таблица с 14 млн. записей:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`id`),
  KEY `events_person` USING BTREE (`person`),
  KEY `events_date` USING BTREE (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=14017398 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
```

Настроены индексы, запросы с условиями WHERE с полями из индекса отрабатываются очень быстро.

При выполнение запроса с группировкой по полю с индексом выполнение идет очень долго:

```
SELECT person, MAX(`date`) FROM events
GROUP BY person
```

Как можно победить?

Comment: а индексы какие?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, описание индексов есть в вопросе, в схеме таблицы

Comment: а ... а если сделать индекс по `person` и `date` вместе

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, да, это помогло, спасибо.